# Will freezing layers in tensorflow save model update time?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a model using transfer learning method, which involves loading and freezing a very large embedding layer. As training speed is also what I concern in this task, I expect freezing layers to also boost training speed. However, I haven't observed any speed improvement at all.

I freeze the embedding layer using

```
self.embedding_layer.trainable = False
```

And did observered non-trainable parameters increased in model summary

As the frozen layers may occur in the middle of a model, and the gradients need to be passed down to the first several trainable layers, I reckon tensorflow still calculate the gradients of frozen layers but just skip them during updating stage.

If my guess is correct, is there any way to remove the frozen layer from gradient calculation?

Comment: I suspect that you are right, but also that the speedup is negligible. In the forward pass, you still need to look up the words. In the backward pass, when the parameters are not frozen, most of them will not require a gradient because they are not used. When the parameters are frozen, their gradients are most likely not calculated if they are not required.